# limpando variáveis com preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Como utilizar o função `preg_match()` para remover caracteres especiais e permitir `.`, `@` e acentos?

Caso não seja possível fazer com essa função, qual outra posso utilizar para ter o mesmo resultado?

Exemplo:

```
$exemplo1=preg_match("[expressão]" , '/*João Paulo/');  
$exemplo2 = preg_match("[expressão]" , 'joao2@hotmail.com-+');

$echo = $exemplo1 // João Paulo
echo = $exemplo2 // joao2@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar um exemplo de entrada e saída esperada?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta da uma olhada pf

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar dessa forma, valida email, depois a senha usando a função [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

```
$email = "email@email.com";
$nome = "João Silva";
$regex_nome = '/^[a-zA-ZãÃáÁàÀêÊéÉèÈíÍìÌôÔõÕóÓòÒúÚùÙûÛçÇºª\' \']+$/';
$regex_email = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';
$email = (preg_match($regex_email, $email))?$email:"email inválido";
$nome = (preg_match($regex_nome, $nome))?$nome:"nome inválido";

var_dump($email);
var_dump($nome);
```

Também pode ser usado o [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) para essa finalidade, dê uma lida.

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `preg_replace`:

```
$exemplo1 = preg_replace ('/[\/*\&%#\$+-]/', '', '/*João Paulo/');
echo $exemplo1;
```

OUTPUT:

> João Paulo

Exemplo 2:

```
$exemplo2 = preg_replace ('/[\/*\&%#\$+-]/', '', 'joao2@hotmail.com-+');
echo $exemplo2;
```

OUTPUT:

> joao2@hotmail.com

Answer (score -1):

```
$nome = preg_replace('/[\*\&%#\$+-]/', '', $nome);
$email = preg_replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\_]/, '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $email));
```